# 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class "MyVendor\SubOrder\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\View\Interceptor" does not exist

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-controller

I am creating a suborder view page in BackOffice that retrieves data from the customized table. However, I received an error on above topic when I click the view button in my customized grid. Did I write the wrong code?

app/code/MyVendor/SubOrder/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/View.php

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\SubOrder\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use MyVendor\SubOrder\Model\ResourceModel\SubOrder\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class View extends Action
{
/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $subOrderCollectionFactory;

/**
 * View constructor.
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 * @param CollectionFactory $subOrderCollectionFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    CollectionFactory $subOrderCollectionFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->subOrderCollectionFactory = $subOrderCollectionFactory;
}

/**
 * Load the page defined in view.xml layout file
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    var_dump($orderId); die;
    $orderCollection = $this->subOrderCollectionFactory->create();
    $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $orderId);
    $order = $orderCollection->getFirstItem();

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Order #%1', $order->getIncrementId()));
    return $resultPage;
}
 }
?>
```

I created an action column for viewing the order details
app/code/MyVendor/SubOrder/view/adminhtml/ui_component/myvendor_suborder_order_listing.xml

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="MyVendor\SubOrder\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">myvendor_suborder/order/view</item>
                <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </actionsColumn>
```

app/code/MyVendor/SubOrder/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ViewAction.php

```
<?php

 namespace MyVendor\SubOrder\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

 use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

 class ViewAction extends Column
 {
/**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlBuilder;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param ContextInterface $context
 * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
 * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 * @param array $components
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
            $item[$fieldName]['view'] = [
                'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    $this->getData('config/viewUrlPath'),
                    [
                        $this->getData('config/urlEntityParamName') => $item['entity_id']
                    ]
                ),
                'label' => __('View')
            ];
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

}

Comment: Run setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you register entry of myvendor_suborder in your etc/adminhtml/routes.xml like below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route frontName="myvendor_suborder" id="myvendor_suborder">
        <module before="Magento_Backend" name="MyVendor_SubOrder"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

Comment: Yes I have it but still same error

Comment: Have you tried php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ?

Comment: it's ok after running setup:static-content:deploy